# Is there anyway to order/sort json array of objects for numbers using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to order JSON array of objects using lodash "orderBy" method. I need to order by both ASC and DESC with the "key" which I can provide. But when giving "id" its not working as expected. This is my input,

```
[
   {

      "disable":"0",
      "id":"37",
      "name":"abcd",
      "owner":"john",
   },
   {

      "disable":"1",
      "id":"38",
      "name":"test",
      "owner":"paul",
   },
    {

      "disable":"1",
      "id":"9",
      "name":"value1",
      "owner":"Khan",
   },
    {

      "disable":"1",
      "id":"7",
      "name":"value2",
      "owner":"Cathrine",
   },
    {

      "disable":"1",
      "id":"8",
      "name":"value4",
      "owner":"Venba",
   },
    {

      "disable":"1",
      "id":"2",
      "name":"value5",
      "owner":"Hawk",
   },
    {

      "disable":"1",
      "id":"4",
      "name":"value7",
      "owner":"other",
   },
]
```

I am using the methods like below, but its not working as expected as "id" columns is in string.

```
_.orderBy(data, [{'id': Number}], 'desc');
```

My current output is,

```
[
   {
      "disable": "0",
      "id": "37",
      "name": "abcd",
      "owner": "john"
   },
   {
      "disable": "1",
      "id": "38",
      "name": "test",
      "owner": "paul"
   },
   {
      "disable": "1",
      "id": "9",
      "name": "value1",
      "owner": "Khan"
   },
   {
      "disable": "1",
      "id": "7",
      "name": "value2",
      "owner": "Cathrine"
   },
   {
      "disable": "1",
      "id": "8",
      "name": "value4",
      "owner": "Venba"
   },
   {
      "disable": "1",
      "id": "2",
      "name": "value5",
      "owner": "Hawk"
   },
   {
      "disable": "1",
      "id": "4",
      "name": "value7",
      "owner": "other"
   }
]
```

Is there any method to sort it properly. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback in `_.orderBy` and return the numeric representation of string value that id fields contains. eg: `o => parseInt(o.id)`

Here is a snippet:

```js
let data = [{"disable":"0","id":"37","name":"abcd","owner":"john"},{"disable":"1","id":"38","name":"test","owner":"paul"},{"disable":"1","id":"9","name":"value1","owner":"Khan"},{"disable":"1","id":"7","name":"value2","owner":"Cathrine"},{"disable":"1","id":"8","name":"value4","owner":"Venba"},{"disable":"1","id":"2","name":"value5","owner":"Hawk"},{"disable":"1","id":"4","name":"value7","owner":"other"}];

console.log('Sorted Data: ', _.orderBy(data, o => parseInt(o.id), 'desc'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```